# Skip the shape delete event

Tags: vba, visio

The feature I want to implement is when the user decides to delete a shape, I want them to have a warning message with yes or no options. If they select no, I don't want the shape to be deleted.

The only solution I can come up with is locking deletion of every shape and using the OnBeforeShapeDelete Event. If the user chooses yes, the deletion protection is removed. If the user chooses no, it won't delete, but I'm annoyed having that prottection bubble popping up everytime(can that be turned off?).

So is there a way in the OnBeforeShape Event where I could skip the shape's delete event? Or any other solutions? Thanks!

Comment: Would `Application.EnableEvents = False` be an answer?

Comment: Not a bad idea, the question would then be how to turn it back on if events are turned off?

Comment: `Application.EnableEvents = True` to turn it on.

Comment: Well yea lol, but since events are turned off, what can trigger that statement?

Comment: I really do not know how your code looks like, but in general you may think of something, depending on your code. `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` in the event is another good option.

Comment: Now that is something I could use, Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The events beginning with QueryCancel allow you to intrupt the flow.  So, for example, adding this to ThisDocument would allow you to not delete a selection based on whether its PrimaryItem was derived from the 'Process' master:

```
Private Function Document_QueryCancelSelectionDelete(ByVal Selection As IVSelection) As Boolean
    Dim queryResult As Boolean
    Dim shp As Shape
    Set shp = Selection.PrimaryItem
    If Not shp Is Nothing Then
        If Not shp.Master Is Nothing Then
            If shp.Master.NameU = "Process" Then
                Dim res As VbMsgBoxResult
                res = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to delete '" & shp.NameID & "'?", vbYesNo, "Delete Process shape?")
                If Not res = vbYes Then
                    queryResult = True
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If

    'Return True to cancel the event
    'Return False to let it continue
    Document_QueryCancelSelectionDelete = queryResult

End Function
```

You're always going to be dealing with Selection, rather than Shape delete events as that's all that's surfaced for the cancelable events, but you can easily iterate through your Selection and identify if it's a shape of interest.  Listening can happen at Application, Document (as above) or Page level depending on your needs.

Answer (score 2):

You may use

`Application.DisplayAlerts = False`

and then

`Application.DisplayAlerts = True`

in the shape event.

Answer (score 0):

So I learned that you cannot prevent a deletion of a shape through the BeforeDeleteEvent. If the shape has LockDelete = 1, the BeforeDeleteEvent will not trigger. So the only way to delete an object through a Message Box is through a UI Form that can be triggered by buttons or other control events.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Private Function AxDrawingControl1_QueryCancelSelectionDelete(sender As 
   Object, e As AxMicrosoft.Office.Interop.VisOcx.EVisOcx_QueryCancelSelectionDeleteEvent) As Boolean Handles AxDrawingControl1.QueryCancelSelectionDelete

    Dim Shp As Shape, SelectedShapes As Visio.Selection

    Dim pg As Visio.Page = AxDrawingControl1.Window.Application.ActivePage

    SelectedShapes = e.selection
    For i = 1 To SelectedShapes.Count

        Shp = SelectedShapes(i)
        If MessageBox.Show("Do you want delete - " & Shp.Name, "", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) = DialogResult.Yes Then

            e.selection.Item(i).Delete()

        Else

        End If

    Next

    Return AxDrawingControl1_QueryCancelSelectionDelete = False

End Function
```